# What happens when I open a file? Is a temporary copy of the file created?

Tags: operating-systems

When I open up a file two different editors, vscode and sublime, changes saved in vscode are visible directly in sublime text. Same doesn't work with nano text editor. Any help?

Comment: Editors will have separate buffers in memory. Sublime Text watches for changes on disk and updates its buffer. Nano doesn't.

Comment: Time allowing, visit [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-cs-site?r=SearchResults&s=2|351.0732).